# How to extract string between other string and number in R?

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I have a vector:

`a <- c("{.package:base73","for.package:base476",":.package:base9","print.package:graphics834")`

and I need to extract string between package: and the first number.

So the output should be:
`c("base", "base", "base", "graphics")`

I tried this but it doesn't work as i wish:

```
b <- "{.package:base71"
gsub(".*package:(.+)[1-9]+", "\\1", b)
```

Edit: I want to use only `base` package*

Comment: If you make `(.+)` non-greedy with `(.+?)`, your example specifically with `b` works. Currently it is greedy, so your capture group grabs `base7` instead of just `base`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a minimal change to code of OP,

```
gsub(".*package:|[1-9]+", "\\1", a)

#[1] "base"     "base"     "base"     "graphics"
```

Comment: Is `gsub(".*package:(.+?)\\d+", "\\1", a)` the same?

Comment: `\\d+` would be better since `[1-9]` would miss `0` but `[0-9]` is also just a minimal change to your code.

Comment: @Derf, or just `\\d`.

Answer (score 3):

Using a capture group `()`, at minimum one character in between `.+`, non-greedy match `?` and a digit directly following `\d`:

```r
library(stringr)
str_extract(a, "package:(.+?)\\d", group = 1)
```

```r
[1] "base"     "base"     "base"     "graphics"
```

Comment: Can You do the same with `base` package?

Comment: Sure, the @Derf showed a base solution. `stringr` has nice "extract" functions, but a good strategy with `sub()` or `gsub()` is to match the entire line by adding those `.*` at the start and end of each string, you can even add `^` or `$` if you like to match start and end of line, like: `sub("^.*package:(.+?)\\d.*$", "\\1", a)`. Also, `\d` and `[0-9]` are the same thing (though `\d` might match digits in other languages)

Answer (score 2):

You can directly extract the non-digit chars after `package:` with the base R code using `regmatches`/`regexec`

```r
a <- c("{.package:base73","for.package:base476",":.package:base9","print.package:graphics834")
unlist(regmatches(a, regexec("package:\\K\\D+", a, perl=TRUE)))
```

See this [R demo](https://ideone.com/dqMKfB) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5YIar3/1).

*Details*:

- `package:` - a literal tgext
- `\K` - omit the text matched so far
- `\D+` - matches one or more non-digit chars.